# SmtpClient.Send is working, but SmtpClient.SendMailAsync is not working on smtp.office365.com

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I developed two methods: SendEmailBySmtp() and SendEmailAsyncBySmtp() that is using SmtpClient.Send and SmtpClient.SendMailAsync respectively.
Currently the first method is working, but the second is not. It has no error, but no email out.
How can I fixed it?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SendEmailBySmtp();
        SendEmailAsyncBySmtp();
    }

    static void SendEmailBySmtp()
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage() 
        { 
            From = new MailAddress("test@example.com", "Test User"), 
            Subject = "Subject", 
            Body = "Body"
        };
        message.To.Add("test@example.com");
        message.CC.Add("test@example.com");
        message.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@example.com", "password");
            client.Send(message);
        }
    }

    static async Task SendEmailAsyncBySmtp()
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
        {
            From = new MailAddress("test@example.com", "Test User"),
            Subject = "Subject",
            Body = "Body"
        };
        message.To.Add("test@example.com");
        message.CC.Add("test@example.com");
        message.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@example.com", "password");
            await client.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the `Main` method you forget to await the second call. Because in the main method you cannot use await keyword you have to manually "await" the thread

Just do it like below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SendEmailBySmtp();
        SendEmailAsyncBySmtp().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

And the answer to your question is: the program ends before the `SendMailAsync` do the job, so the email sending operation is stopped before it is sent.

Comment: I got error: "'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'RunAsync' and no extension method 'RunAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'". However, I understood your concept, I changed to SendEmailAsyncBySmtp().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); It's working. Thank you very much.

Comment: @akkapolk you are right I wrote the code without running it. I will change the answer

Comment: I had this same issue but it works fine in my code that was not updated with nuget. Now this function errors with "failure sending email". I am trying to see what package is causing this issue now but this solution doesnt work.